# How to install GoogleAds-IMA-iOS-SDK-For-AdMob old pod version 3.0.beta.6?

Tags: ios, google-api, cocoapods

Recently google decided to update this pod (GoogleAds-IMA-iOS-SDK-For-AdMob) to 3.0.beta.7 making some changes that are breaking my app that is using 3.0.beta.6. I tried to install the old version by setting specifically it in my podfile  but still doesn't care and it installs the new one.

The question is:

- Is there any way to install an old version of this pod?
- Is google using a wrong syntax what makes cocoapods not to understand the version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the latest version you would use

`pod 'GoogleAds-IMA-iOS-SDK-For-AdMob'`

To pull in a specific version you'd want

`pod 'GoogleAds-IMA-iOS-SDK-For-AdMob', '3.0.beta.6'`

A bit more info about pod versioning is available at http://guides.cocoapods.org/using/the-podfile.html